# All solutions of $1 = \exp(\exp(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

I am so confused about this problem, although I think I know how to solve it.

First of all, I am going to share part of my work before asking a question.

We have $1 = \exp(\exp(z))$, and this implies $\exp(z) \in \ker \exp = 2 \pi i \mathbb{Z}.$

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the condition above, then consider for each $n$.

If $n=0$, then we can't have any solution since $\exp(z) \neq 0$  $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.

So, we are left with two cases such as $n < 0$ and $n>0$.

i) If $n>0$, then $\exp (z) \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}^{\leq 0}$, so we can use the principal branch of the logarithm here.

First, pick an arbitrary $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$.

$\Rightarrow \exp (z_0) =2\pi i n $ for some $n>0$.

$\Rightarrow \text{Log}(\exp(z_0))=\text{Log}(i2\pi n)$

Then by a theorem, $\exists k \in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t
$$z_0 = \text{Log} (i2 \pi n) + i2\pi k$$
$$= \log(2 \pi n) + i \arg(i2\pi n) + i2\pi k$$
$$= \log(2\pi n) + i\frac{\pi}{2} +i2 \pi k$$
$$ =\log(2\pi n) + i(\frac{\pi}{2} +2 \pi k) \; \; \; \; \text{for some} \; n \in \mathbb{Z}^{>0}, k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

And we use a similar method for the ii) $n<0$ case.

Thus, the final answer would be a generalized version of this. (End of Solution)

However, as shown above, this was solved for an arbitrary point. And, I'm having trouble with generalizing the result.

When generalizing, what do we need to say?

Do we just change $z_0$ to $z$, and some $n,k$ to all $n,k$? (But, I doubt this one could really be an answer as it seems possible to lose some integers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex solutions of $e^{e^z}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729958)

Comment: I think wolfram gives as a solution $z=\log(2i\pi n_1)+2i\pi n_2$,  $n_1, n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I think so. Thanks for sharing this. Then, my last sentence would be the answer. It looks like I was confused because of my lack of understanding of this topic.